# Tag added when profile used

Tags: drupal, profile, tags

When the reserved profile "New Individual" is used (just the 3 standard fields) it also adds one of the tags from the tag tree (the same one each time).  Why is that happening and how to stop it from adding the tag.

Comment: Do you have civirules or drupal rule module configured on the site? Probably, they might have a rule configured which adds tag to the user everytime this profile is submitted.

Comment: I do not believe so. We are not using civicrm rules or any special configuration for the site.